# How to align one vertex to X, Y or Z of another vertex

Tags: modeling, workflow

sometimes I need to complete tasks like in this video, any easier way to connect this vertex to edge?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVCdgss5gKI&feature=youtu.be

And also, sometimes I need to align one vertex in 3D space by using X, Y or Z of other vertex, is there any combination of keys which can do it?

Comment: before your cuts (if several), set pivot as active element, after the cut, make select and active the wanted vertex, then scale X (or Y or Z) 0...

Comment: A bit better : is you start to cut from the existing vertex, it stays active after the cut : so method in the previous comment is faster

Comment: Yep, I know this way and it's working, but it's align both vertex to median point between them, isn't it? What if I want to align first vertex to second or second to position of first?

Comment: The key is to set the pivot point to active element first (so that this is not the median which is reached)

Comment: Please edit the title of this question so it is descriptive of the task you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that quicker,

**first method**

set the pivot point to active element and start your cut from the existing point (as this will keep this point active).

Then scale to 0 using the wanted axis :

[image]

**second method**

Use '*offset edge slide*' <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

During the movement place the mouse along the shortest edge and hit <kbd>E</kbd>.

After that you'll need to remove doubles or merge the vertices.

[image]